# Why my node.tpl.php not work at drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am a beginner of drupal.
I build a new theme without sub-theming, the file structure like that:

```
sites/
|-all/
  |-themes/
    |-mytheme/
      |-templates/
      | |-maintenance-page.tpl.php
      | |-node.tpl.php
      | |-page--front.tpl.php
      | |-page--node.tpl.php
      | |-page.tpl.php
      |-template.php
      |-mytheme.info
```

I debug with FirePHP and open `http://localhost/?q=node/1`, and found that page--node.tpl.php was included and node.tpl.php was not. Why my node.tpl.php was not be included and How should I do? (P.S. I has clear the caches)

Answer (score 0):

Only one template file at the time can be used and based on requested page Drupal has decided to use page--node.tpl.php. It's called template suggestion and you can read about it [here](http://drupal.org/node/1089656).

Comment: If page--node.tpl.php is existed, drupal would use pag--node.tpl.php to render the node page, otherwise, it would use page.tpl.php, but it is unrelated with node.tpl.php. page.tpl.php and node.tpl.php are two different template file and they should not conflict.

Answer (score 0):

These templates are **overrides**. 
That means your node--TYPE.tpl.php file will override it's base template which is node.tpl.php file.
So base template will not be used.